# Applications on two Virtual Box VMs and vagrant not connecting

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrant-windows

I have two Virtual Box (Virtual Box version is 4.3.18)windows 2012 server VMs set up using vagrant VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2".

config.vm.network "private_network", ip:"192.168.1.15"

and

config.vm.network "private_network", ip:"192.168.1.12"

On VMs I have NAT and Host Only network with subnet mask 255.255.255.0
On both the machines NAT IP is 10.0.2.15 with subnet 255.255.255.0.

I am able to ping Guest<========>Guest both ways

Guest====>Host

Host=====>Guest

On Host , Virtual Box Host only adapter has IP 192.168.1.1 and subnet 255.255.255.0 .

I have two different applications one on 192.168.1.15 and other on 192.168.1.12 which are not talking to each other.

One of the applications says "Register to your local IP 10.0.2.15".

Seems like one application is getting the signal but the other application is not getting the signal at all.

These applications connect through each other's IP. I have provided IPs in the required place.